# Как обрезать DataFrame по дате?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

Как обрезать `data['Date']` чтобы DataFrame шел после `1959-07-28`?

Не помогает:

```
data = data.loc['1959-07-27':]
 
Date
1959-07-21
1959-07-22
1959-07-23
1959-07-24
1959-07-27
1959-07-28
1959-07-29
1959-07-30
1959-07-31
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Вариант 1:**

```
In [12]: df.query("Date >= '1959-07-28'")
Out[12]:
        Date
5 1959-07-28
6 1959-07-29
7 1959-07-30
8 1959-07-31
```

**Вариант 2:**

```
In [13]: df.loc[df["Date"] >= "1959-07-28"]
Out[13]:
        Date
5 1959-07-28
6 1959-07-29
7 1959-07-30
8 1959-07-31
```